# Big Sur - How to restart the menu bar on Mac

Tags: terminal, finder, big-sur

https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/02/24/restart-frozen-menu-bar-extras-mac/

- does anyone know a working command for Big Sur? I tried this but doesn't look like it's working. Terminal and activity monitor.